# how to mange data from csv file - php

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

i have an multidimensional array that i parsed from csv file.
it looks like that:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6434
        [1] => 2018-12-27 13:06:13
        [2] => 186
        [3] => 995543303675
        [4] => 87.190.148.217
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 7543
        [1] => 2018-12-27 13:57:38
        [2] => 280
        [3] => 27564577728
        [4] => 41.77.56.40
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6434
        [1] => 2018-12-27 14:13:10
        [2] => 212
        [3] => 995947425447
        [4] => 218.99.136.57
    )
```

The resulting page should show statistics table with following fields: 
  1.Customer ID 
  2.Total number of all calls 
  3.Total duration of all calls

Customer can call more then ones.

the outpot needs to look somting like that:

As a result report for Customer ID 7232 we have: 
 Number of all customer calls: 8 
 Total duration of all customer calls: 1208 seconds.

im not sour how to mange the data for implimating this request. And I'd love suggestions.

I thought to build a class called Call.
So that I can manage the variables.
is it true? So what should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: With a foreach loop, and some HTML.

Comment: and if a Customer can call more then ones?

Comment: Then you group them based on the customer number.  Your going to have to show way more code then an array for anyone to be able to help you.  The question as it is is way to general.

Comment: What is this data? How can I know where to find number of calls and all the other data items?